# Xcode 8.2 syntax coloring for variables

Tags: xcode, colors

```
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!
```

I'm trying to use a difference color for variable, in this case, "display".
However, Xcode takes "display" as a part of "plain text".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Xcode *will* highlight the variable; just not in right where you declared it:

[image]

Comment: How about the names of the parameters in functions? Seems Xcode just shoves this under "plain text" as well :/